# One UIButton play multiple sounds randomly. Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

I need to create a button where when I press it, just one sounds gets played. When I press it again, I want a different sound to get play. I have 4 sounds that I want to get played randomly. Therefor when I press the button let's say 8 times, I will hear 8 sounds, randomly.

I put the sound file names in an array and implemented the arc4random to randomise. I am working with AVFoundation and that's where I get stuck. I do not know how to play this array.

I know how to play 1 sound, but not how to implement this in the button. Anyone any idea?

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let soundFilenames = ["sound_1.mp3", "sound_2.mp3"]
let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(soundFilenames.count)))
let selectedFilename = soundFilenames[randomIndex]

@IBAction func tap(sender: UIButton) {
   // Audio code?
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Edit :

```
@IBAction func tap(sender: UIButton) {

    let soundFilenames = ["Sound1.mp3", "Sound2.mp3"]
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(soundFilenames.count)))
    let selectedFilename = soundFilenames[randomIndex]


    let sound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("selectedFilename", ofType: "mp3")!)

    var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer?
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: sound, error: nil)
    audioPlayer!.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer!.play()

}
```

Edit 2 :

```
var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer?

@IBAction func tap(sender: UIButton) {

    let soundFilenames = ["Sound1", "Sound2"]
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(soundFilenames.count)))
    let selectedFilename = soundFilenames[randomIndex]


    let sound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("selectedFilename", ofType: "mp3")!)

    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: sound, error: nil)
    audioPlayer!.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer!.play()

}
```

Comment: Or, if as you claim you _do_ know how to play 1 sound, what's the problem? Show your code for playing 1 sound with `selectedFilename` plugged in. Again, it's unclear what the problem can be.

Comment: I need to use AVFoundation AVAudioPlayer to play the sound correct? I know how to play one sound after I tap the button. I just don't know how to implement the audio player So I can actually press the button and say play sounds from this array.

Comment: I edited my initial post. I'm just confused because of the array. So please, if you have any idea on how to make this work, i'm all ears.

Comment: That code is never going to work because `audioPlayer` is a local variable and so your AVAudioPlayer vanishes in a puff of smoke before it can play the sound. You need this to be an instance variable of your class.

Comment: Also if you're going to be saying `"mp3"` in your call to `pathForResource`, then `"mp3"` should not also be present in the strings your manipulating.

Comment: I applied the changes you suggested as shown in edit 2. It still does not work. I get this error -> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: So debug. You are the one who is force-unwrapping all those Optionals. Not wise. How do I know whether you even _have_ sound files called _Sound1.mp3_ and _Sound2.mp3_? Anything could be going on here. Figure it out. Test for nil before you unwrap if you don't want to risk crashing.

Answer (score 0):

If that is your exact copy/pasted code, your let sound statement could use a proofread.

```
let sound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("selectedFilename", ofType: "mp3")!)
```

not

```
let sound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("selectedFilemane", ofType: "mp3")!)
```

You mentioned you know how to play a sound, but have you done that yet with this code?

Comment: I changed that when I posted it right away, weird that it still shows that. Thanks though